# How can I enforce the same schema when reading multiple CSV files? spark.read.csv(*list_of_csv_files, schema = schema) not working

Tags: pyspark

The code in question is `df = spark.read.csv(*list_of_csv_files, schema = schema)`.

Without schema specification, letting it infer the schema, this works.

However, I need to enforce a specific schema on the datasets. I also tried `*schema` but no luck.

Would this be possible?

Comment: please specify what exactly is not working, do you get an error?

Comment: What error do you get? What's are the details of the schema you are passing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter `schema=schema` in `read.csv()`. All CSVs must have columns in same order (column names can be any) and data types should be compatible for casting from string to the required type.

There is an [option "inferSchema"](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html); but it is less restrictive compared to `schema` parameter and in cases where the header names differ in different CSVs, the columns will be defaulted to string type.

Following example recreates this:

There are four files with variations in column names, column order and value data types. We import all files in the folder at once:

```bash
! ls /content/sample_data/test

Book1.csv
Book2.csv
Book3.csv
Book4.csv
```

**Book1.csv** has an int, a float and a bool type column:

```bash
! cat /content/sample_data/test/Book1.csv

int_col,float_col,bool_col
1,0.5,True
```

**Book2.csv** has columns in same order; but all values are strings. Since, the types are compatible to cast from string, they are successfully read and casted to proper type:

```bash
! cat /content/sample_data/test/Book2.csv

int_col,float_col,bool_col
"2","0.75","True"
```

**Book3.csv** has columns in same order; but column names are different (the types are compatible, though, to cast from string). They are read in order and casted to type as per schema order:

```bash
! cat /content/sample_data/test/Book3.csv

x_col,y_col,z_col
3,0.25,False
```

**Book4.csv** has similar column names; but the order is different, and hence the values are read as `null` due to cast failure:

```bash
! cat /content/sample_data/test/Book4.csv

bool_col,float_col,int_col
True,0.9,4
```

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, FloatType, BooleanType

schema = StructType([
    StructField("int_col", IntegerType()),
    StructField("float_col", FloatType()),
    StructField("bool_col", BooleanType())
])

df = spark.read.option("header",True).csv("/content/sample_data/test", schema=schema)

df.show()

+-------+---------+--------+
|int_col|float_col|bool_col|
+-------+---------+--------+
|      1|      0.5|    true| #Book1.csv has an int, a float and a bool type column
|      2|     0.75|    true| #Book2.csv has columns in same order; but all values are strings. Since, the types are compatible to cast from string, they are successfully read and casted to proper type
|      3|     0.25|   false| #Book3.csv has columns in same order; but column names are different (the types are compatible, though, to cast from string). They are read in order and casted to type as per schema order
|   null|      0.9|    null| #Book4.csv has similar column names; but the order is different, and hence the values are read as null due to cast failure
+-------+---------+--------+

df.printSchema()

root
 |-- int_col: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- float_col: float (nullable = true)
 |-- bool_col: boolean (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that if just a directory is called to the CSV file argument for reading the file, it calls all the files. Good to know!